# Creating dataframe from another dataframe and list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have a list of names like this

```
names= [Josh,Jon,Adam,Barsa,Fekse,Bravo,Talyo,Zidane]
```

and i have a dataframe like this

```
    Number  Names  
0   1       Josh   
1   2       Jon    
2   3       Adam   
3   4       Barsa  
4   5       Fekse  
5   6       Barsa  
6   7       Barsa 
7   8       Talyo  
8   9       Jon  
9   10      Zidane
```

i want to create a dataframe that will have all the names in names list and the corresponding numbers from this dataframe grouped, for the names that does not have corresponding numbers there should be an asterisk like below

```
Names Number
Josh  1
Jon   2,9
Adam  3
Barsa 4,6,7
Fekse 5
Bravo *
Talyo 8
Zidane 10
```

Do we have any built in functions to get this done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` with `str.join`, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with your `names` list:

```
res = df.groupby('Names')['Number'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))).to_frame()\
        .reindex(names).fillna('*').reset_index()

print(res)

    Names Number
0    Josh      1
1     Jon    2,9
2    Adam      3
3   Barsa  4,6,7
4   Fekse      5
5   Bravo      *
6   Talyo      8
7  Zidane     10
```

Comment: The Number Column for certain names will have more than 1 number, so is that a list? how can i convert that to a string

Comment: @foret, The Number Column will be a comma-separated string (or `'*'`) here.

Comment: actually i am getting the numbers in list form [4,6,7] [1] and so on

Comment: @foret, Are you using `lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))` as per my solution?

Comment: oops, i am noticing it only now..let me try that